# Writing Arrays using grep

Tags: ruby, arrays, grep

I'm trying to search through a specified string and assign the results to an array.
Opening and writing to "input.txt" and "ms3.txt" files works fine. putting a normal string like  `reassign << "hello"` in works fine its just when i use `line.grep` and the regex following it prints nothing to the console or the ms3 file it doesn't even throw up any errors 
i've also tried a search and replace: `reassign << line.gsub(/[abc]/, '£')`
Here's the code

```
# encoding: utf-8
#!/usr/bin/ruby

file = File.open("input.txt", "w+")

reassign = []
  file.each_line do |line|
    reassign << line.grep(/[abc]/)
     end

new_file = File.open("ms3.txt", "w+")
new_file.puts(reassign)
new_file.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be streamlined a lot to make it more Ruby-like, and to make it behave better:

```
# encoding: utf-8
#!/usr/bin/ruby

file = File.open("input.txt", "w+")

reassign = []
  file.each_line do |line|
    reassign << line.grep(/[abc]/)
    end

new_file = File.open("ms3.txt", "w+")
new_file.puts(reassign)
new_file.close
```

1. `#!` lines *have* to be first, so reverse the `encoding` and "slash-bang" lines.
2. [`open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html#method-c-open) takes a block, which will allow Ruby to automatically close the file when the block exits. This is a very powerful, and smart thing to do, as it keeps your file I/O environment clean. It's possible, and often a problem as in your code, to open files but never close them, which can exhaust all the file handles on a machine if it's done in a loop, causing all apps to fail. Using the block form will avoid this.
3. The IO class has [`foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html#method-c-foreach), which makes it simple to iterate over the lines of a file. Take advantage of it instead of opening the file then using `each_line`, because it simplifies your code.

Here's how I'd initially write your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# encoding: utf-8

reassign = []
File.foreach("input.txt") do |line|
  reassign << line[/[abc]/]
end

File.write("ms3.txt", reassign.join("\n"))
```

But, after refactoring it I'd end up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# encoding: utf-8

File.open('ms3.txt', 'w') do |fo|
  fo.puts File.foreach('input.txt').grep(/[abc/])
end
```

1. The `open` opens the output file using a block to take advantage of automatically closing the file when the block exits.
2. `foreach` is an iterator, and normally is used with a block to pass each line read into the block. Instead, I'm letting [`grep`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) read all the lines found and search for the pattern.
3. Any lines found by `grep` that match the pattern are returned as an array to `puts` which will iterate over them, appending `"\n"` to the end of each.
4. `fo.puts` directs the output of `puts` to the output file.
5. `end` causes the block to exit, which causes `open` to close the file.

That's untested but looks correct.

Comment: wow thank you, you make it look so easy. by any chance do you know anything about using regex's in Ruby. my search instead of the "[abc]" is "<div class="ms3">.*?(\n.*?)+<\/div>" but it stops working as soon as i get to the "<" in "<\/div>" i've tested it using regex pal and the search definitely finds what its looking it just doesn't seem to work when its in this code.

Comment: That's an entirely different question, which needs to be asked separately, not as a comment. To parse HTML/XML, you need to use a parser, not regular expressions. Look at [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org), search SO for [tag:nokogiri] tagged questions, take a whack at figuring it out yourself, and if you still have problems ask for help.

Comment: i'm not sure that i'm trying to parse it (if i understand what parsing means correctly) i just need to make search and replaces, or in this case extractions, from a text document that contains HTML, is that the same as parsing?

Comment: No, that's not using a parser. XML/HTML is too complex to use normal search/replace because regular expressions can't easily handle the tags. Instead, using a parser, like libXML, via Nokogiri, we can easily find sections, extract/delete/add/modify elements including text, and even rewrite the changed XML/HTML. You can try to do shortcuts but eventually you'll get bit, so you might as well start out doing it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You open `"input.txt"` with open mode `"w+"`. According to the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode), this truncates your file to zero length. An empty file doesn't contain any lines and  therefore, `file.each_line` doesn't invoke the block.

   If you want to read from the file, use `"r"`, which is the default:

   ```
   file = File.open("input.txt")
   ```
2. You don't close `file`. Use the block form which closes the file automatically:

   ```
   File.open("input.txt") do |file|
     # ...
   end
   ```
3. `line` is a `String` and there's no `String#grep` method. But since `File` includes `Enumerable`, you can use [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) instead:

   ```
   reassign = file.grep(/[abc]/)
   ```

A complete example:

```
File.open("input.txt") do |file|
  reassign = file.grep(/[abc]/)

  File.open("ms3.txt", "w+") do |new_file|
    new_file.puts(reassign)
  end
end
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks so much! As you can tell i'm a complete beginner, i didn't realise what you put between the "||" parenthesis actually mattered i thought it was just a stand in for whatever was passing though it, if that makes sense, thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to vote up answers that are helpful. If my answer solves your problem, you might even want to mark it as accepted.