# Multiply each item in an array by each item in another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

In Ruby, how can one multiply every element in one array by every element in another array, such that:

```
a = [1,2,3]

b = [4,5,6]

c = a*b = [4,5,6,8,10,12,12,15,18]
```

Comment: I see now why you selected an answer so quickly. The author of that question asked you to do that just a few minutes after you posted the question! It is very bad form for him to have done that. He would not have done so had the question been posted by an experienced SO member, because he knows his request would not have fallen on deaf ears. I suggest that in future you wait at least a couple of hours,  as you don't want to discourage others from posting answers or short-circuit those who are still working on their answers. There's no rush...

Comment: @CarySwoveland the OP appreciated the answer and said that it solved the problem. Its author in return asked if the OP could accept it, even providing a link to help section which explains how accepting works in detail. I see no bad form here.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is not beautiful but returns what you want.

`a.map{|aa| b.map{|bb| bb * aa}}.flatten`

Comment: I would never, never, never upvote an answer given by anyone who asks a newbie SO for it after just a few minutes. Shame!

Comment: Thanks for your advice. You are right. I just thought telling how to use StackOverflow is a great behavior.

Comment: Correction to my earlier comment: "...who asks an SO newbie to mark their answer as selected after just a few minutes."

Comment: @Sagar, the answer is correct, so I don't think it deserves downvotes.

Comment: New users sometimes don't know that answers can be accepted. So if a new user says _"thanks, that works"_ (aka solved the problem) but doesn't accept the answer, it's perfectly fine to ask them to do so.

Comment: Upvote from me – you answered within 5 minutes, your solution works and it solved the OP's problem.

Comment: @Stefan, I disagree, strenuously. Firstly, we can agree that many SO newbies are also Ruby rubies, meaning that they may not know SO rules and etiquette and may not be able to determine if an answer is a good one. All SO veterans know this. I've seen numerous instances where the author of the first answer posted asked for the greenie and got it, and the answer was poor, sometimes even wrong. If the asker exits the room before other members offer much better answers or point out the flaws in the accepted answer, has he/she been well-served by SO? (cont.)

Comment: ...Even if the asker  stays around, they probably don't know they can revoke or move the greenie. We've both seen absolutely wonderful answers go unrewarded for that reason. It's true that newbies often don't know they are expected to select the answer, but the solution for that is not for authors of answers to say, "gimmie the checkmark!". Rather, they should explain how it works and point out there's no rush to make a selection, that they'd be well-served by waiting for others to post answers. Then they select the answer they find most helpful, if indeed any are helpful. (cont.)

Comment: ...@Stefan, lastly, let me ask you this. Have you *ever* posted the first answer to a question asked by an obvious newbie and said (sic), "If you find that I have answered your question please select my answer"? If the answer is "no", you should ask yourself how that behavior squares with your comment above.  So there!

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've posted similar comments, e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46478857/ruby-calculations-with-gets-chomp-in-a-loop/46490824#comment79941010_46490824) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972633/writing-arrays-using-grep/26973801#comment42484067_26973801). Although I tend phrase them in a more general way.

Comment: For me, the greenie is always subjective because it marks the best answer _for the OP_ in the context of his or her problem. It allows the OP to mark the question as being solved and to pick an answer regardless of votes. Maybe the OP is behind schedule and a quick and dirty answer is more valuable that a clean one posted hours later.

Comment: @Stefan, #1 doesn’t count as you merely suggested (20 or so hours after the question was posted) that an answer be selected. ..but a quick and incorrect answer is not not likely more valuable... We’ll just have to disagree on this one.

Answer (score 10):

For a nice abstraction, can get cartesian product using `product`:

```
a.product(b).map { |aa, bb| aa * bb }
```

Comment: When I see the code like this (once a month at least,) I always wonder what’s wrong with `Enumerable#map_reduce` to be introduced in Ruby core? :)

Comment: Do you (or does a reader) know why [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-product) returns an array rather than an enumerator? An enumerator would have obvious advantages in applications where `product` is chained to an `Enumerable` method. (I expect the reason is forehead-slapping  simple.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I am positive it’s legacy; fwiw, you always are free to `a.enum_for(:product, b)`.

Comment: Thanks, mudsie, er @AlekseiMatiushkin That makes sense and  thanks for the code (which I've tucked away).

Comment: @CarySwoveland the corresponding [ticket #3021](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/3021) says: _"Returning an enumerator today would break compatibility though. I suggest that Array#product(&block) yields to the block and returns self."_ Although I'm not sure what could have broken since it didn't take a block before ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: BTW, `zip` is even worse – it just returns (a useless) `nil` when a block is given.

Comment: @shirakia please change the accepted answer, this one is proper.

Comment: @Stefan, I confess that I never noticed that `product` could take a block. I expect "Returning an enumerator today..." referred to chaining.

Answer (score 5):

This solution makes use of [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) methods to compute (and then flatten) the *outer product* of two vectors.

```
require 'matrix'

(Matrix.column_vector(a) * Matrix.row_vector(b)).to_a.flatten
  #=> [4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18]
```

Like the other two answers to date, this produces a temporary array, which when flattened (if not already flattened) contains `a.size**2` elements. If `a` is so large that this results in a storage problem, you could use a pair of enumerators instead:

```
a.each_with_object([]) { |aa,arr| b.each { |bb| arr << aa*bb } }
  #=> [4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18]
```

The enumerators are as follows.

```
enum_a = a.each_with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each_with_object([])>
aa, arr = enum_a.next
  #=> [1, []]
aa, arr = enum_a.next
  #=> [2, []]
...

enum_b = b.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [4, 5, 6]:each>
bb = enum_b.next
  #=> 4
bb = enum_b.next
  #=> 5
...
```

See [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next). This is how enumerators pass elements to their blocks.

The method [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) is very convenient and not as complex as it may initially seem. For the most part it just saves two lines of code from the following.

```
arr = []
a.each { |aa| b.each { |bb| arr << aa*bb } }
arr
```

Comment: _"the cross-products are all done in C"_ – are you sure? The source code for [`matrix.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_5_3/lib/matrix.rb#L881-L906) looks as if it is implemented in Ruby.

Comment: @Stefan, as I was reading the code at the link you gave you could have knocked me over with a feather. Why? Why? Not why the feather, but why write each and every `Matrix` method in Ruby? The idea of writing numerically demanding methods such as [Matrix#lup_decomposition](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-lup_decomposition) in Ruby boggles the mind. I had assumed an optimized public-domain matrix library written in C had been used (with Ruby wrappers). That also would have been a lot easier than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Tried with following,

```
a.product(b).map { |x| x.inject(&:*) }
```

Amazingly following also solve it,

```
a.map { |x| b.map(&x.method(:*)) }.flatten
```

Comment: The former is a shallow copy of the answer given by @Amadan and the latter is the exact copy of [not the best here] accepted answer. Downvoted.

Comment: Use `(:*)` in your first answer and `flat_map` in your second answer.

Comment: @SagarPandya I personally dislike passing a symbol argument to `reduce` since it is allowed by this method only, all of a sudden, while using `Symbol#to_proc` is the common approach used widely among the whole ruby core.